# Value was undefined for Angular subscribe methods

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, subscribe

I am new to angular.I referred already asked similar questions and even tried.It was not working out.

```
ngOnInit() {
console.log("Inside init function")
this.get_jobs()
console.log("response data",this.responsedata)    #output:Undefined
...
...
}

get_jobs()
{
 this.http.get<resp[]>(API_URL).pipe(
 map((response) => response as resp[] || []))
 .subscribe((data) =>{ 
this.responsedata=data
});
console.log("response data",this.responsedata)   #output:undefined
}
```

As many of them suggested to use observables So I tried but still it was undefined:

```
ngOnInit() {
console.log("Inside init function")
this.get_jobs().subscribe(response=>{console.log(response)});
console.log("response data",this.responsedata)    #output was still Undefined
...
(Based on the response data we have done some implementations)
...
}

get_jobs():Observable<any>
{
 this.http.get<resp[]>(API_URL).pipe(
 map((response) => response as resp[] || []))
 .subscribe((data) =>{ 
this.responsedata=data
});
return of(this.responsedata)
}
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: Max, please check your variable. Firstly, you misspelled `this.response_data` in your `get_jobs` method. Next, `Observable` is async by its own nature and `console.log` function, you're calling right after you subscribed, doesn't guarantee to show a desire value. The question is what you're going to do with your `this.response_data` value?

Answer (score 0):

As your `get_jobs()` method is asynchronous, as others have mentioned, the only reliable place you can `console.log` the return value is within the `subscribe()`. Your second implementation is closer to what you want, but you are still placing your console.log outside of the `subscribe()` so it is still returning `undefined`.

The following will work:

```
ngOnInit() {
  console.log("Inside init function")
  this.get_jobs();
...
...
}

get_jobs(): void {
  this.http.get<resp[]>(API_URL)
    .pipe(
      map(
        (response) => response as resp[] || [])
      )
    .subscribe(
      (data) => { 
        this.responsedata = data
        console.log("response data",this.responsedata)    // Will log whatever 'data' was returned
      }
```

If you want to use `this.responsedata` for something other than `console.log()`, that code also has to go in the `subscribe()`, for example:

```
get_jobs(): void {
  this.http.get<resp[]>(API_URL)
    .pipe(
      map(
        (response) => response as resp[] || [])
      )
    .subscribe(
      (data) => { 
        this.responsedata = data
        this.filterData( this.responsedata )
      }
```

This is a fundamental concept in asynchronous programming. You have to think of the code as a "stream of time" and whatever you want to do has to come explicitly at the end of the "stream", i.e. in the `subscribe()`.

Any code you put outside of the subscribe will happen synchronously and, in most cases, all the synchronous code will run before your asynchronous "stream" has finished. This is why you got `undefined` originally as the `console.log()` happened before `this.responsedata` was assigned.

Edit: Added image to clarify the timeline and hopefully make the concept clearer[image]

Comment: thanks for your reply but i need to use responsedata inside ngonInit. For that,I need to use observables right??

Comment: Unfortunately the short answer is "you can't". But not to worry, it's a common use case to get data from an endpoint and in pretty much all of these scenarios, the code you write to use the endpoint data goes in the `subscribe()`. I've added an image to the answer to demonstrate why. `ngOnInit` finishes running waaaaay before the endpoint has returned data so `this.responsedata` will basically always be undefined in `ngOnInit`. If you want to know why, learn the difference between synchronous and asynchronous code.

Comment: But I have a doubt.I was returning observable from get method and subscribe in ngOnit method.Then the value must come right?

Comment: You were returning an observable outside of the `subscribe()` which, in a similar way, means that you were returning `of(undefined)` as the `http.get` had not yet returned its data. Have you tried putting your logic inside the `subscribe` and checked to see if your code now works?